# Multiply each element of a two dimensional array by 5 (C/C++)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I need to write some piece of code (C/C++) that multiplies each and every element of a two dimensional array by a constant; problem is, the result i'm getting is that instead of the elements of the array, the indexes are the ones that are being multiplied.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
  int m1 [3][3];
  int m2 [3][3];
  int t1, t2;
  int t3, t4;

  for (t1= 0; t1 < 3; t1++){
     for (t2 = 0; t2 < 3; t2++){
        scanf("%i",&m1[t1][t2]);
     }
  }

  for (t3 = 0; t3 < 3; t3++){
     for (t4 = 0; t4 < 3; t4++){
        m2[t3][t4] = m1[t1][t2]* 5;
        printf("%i", m2[t3][t4]);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Select one language tag.

Answer (score 1):

Bad indexing is your problem

```
m2[t3][t4] = m1[t1][t2]* 5; /* Bad Indexes t1 and t2 */
```

You should have done this:

```
m2[t3][t4] = m1[t3][t4]* 5;
```

Anyway, why do you need t3 & t4? You could reuse t1 & t2!

Answer (score 0):

This loop

```
for (t3 = 0; t3 < 3; t3++){
        for (t4 = 0; t4 < 3; t4++){
     m2[t3][t4] = m1[t1][t2]* 5;
                     ^^^^^^
     printf("%i", m2[t3][t4]);

}
}
```

does not make sense.

After the preceding loop `t1` and `t2` are equal to `3` and using them as indices in the second loop results in accessing memory beyond the array `m1`.

It seems you mean

```
for (t3 = 0; t3 < 3; t3++){
        for (t4 = 0; t4 < 3; t4++){
     m2[t3][t4] = m1[t3][t4] * 5;
                     ^^^^^^
     printf( "%i,", m2[t3][t4] );

}
}
```

Pay attention to that the variables used as indices may be declared in the for loop. There is no need to declare them in the beginning of the function main because they are used only in loops. For example

```
for ( size_t t3 = 0; t3 < 3; t3++ )
{
    for ( size_t t4 = 0; t4 < 3; t4++ )
    {
        m2[t3][t4] = m1[t3][t4] * 5;
                        ^^^^^^
        printf( "%i,", m2[t3][t4] );
    }
}
```

And instead of using the magic number 3 you could use a named constant as for example

```
enum { M = 3, N = 3 };
int m1[M][N];
int m2[M][N];

//...

for ( size_t t3 = 0; t3 < M; t3++ )
{
    for ( size_t t4 = 0; t4 < N; t4++ )
    {
        m2[t3][t4] = m1[t3][t4] * 5;
                        ^^^^^^
        printf( "%i,", m2[t3][t4] );
    }
}
```

In this case your program will be more flrxible.

Comment: This is one reason why it's considered best practice to declare your variables only right before you need them, limiting them to as small a scope as possible.